# Where is this park in Montreal, with autumn color trees and pond?

Tags: identify-this, montreal

I found this picture in a folder with photos of our trip to Montreal, Quebec. But we cannot remember where this was taken?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems to be [Beaver Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver_Lake_(Montreal)) ([*Lac aux Castors*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lac_aux_Castors_(Montr%C3%A9al))) in [Mount Royal Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Royal#Mount_Royal_Park) ([*Parc du Mont-Royal*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parc_du_Mont-Royal)):

[image: Google Streetview screenshot]
<sup>Source: [Google Streetview](https://goo.gl/maps/Tf1aMhCYfpeZqGHJ7)</sup>

Comment: thanks! how did you pinpoint this? have you been here before?

Comment: @user1110341 FWIW, *I* pinpointed it from having been there. I use that trail on top of the hill all the time. At first I thought it was Parc Lafontaine [near here](https://goo.gl/maps/5yjRwGkaS6V9b1DRA), but the scale was wrong.

Comment: @user1110341: No, i wasn't there before. I relied on the information from your question and searched for parks in Montreal with lakes / ponds. Lac aux Castors was the first lake i've found. I've concentrated on locating the conifer that's visible in the background as distinctive feature - StreetView was a great help in this case again.